# Laravel 5 : Call a Model in a view

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

In my controller, I've got my models collection in my controller :

```
$ngo = Ngo::where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();
    $projects = $ngo->projects()->get()->toArray();       
    $online_jobs = $ngo->jobs()->online()->get()->toArray();
    $infield_jobs = $ngo->jobs()->inField()->get()->toArray();
    $projects_missions = array_merge($projects, $online_jobs, $infield_jobs)
```

Then in my view, I,'ve call a loop :

```
@foreach ($projects_missions as $j)    
   <h5 class="sBlack">{{ $j['title'] }}</h5>
   @if ($j['type'] == "donation_money")
       @php $current_project = \App\Project::findOrFail($j['id']); @endphp
       <div class="progress-bar"><span class="bar" style="width:{{ $current_project->goalPercentage }}%;"></span></div>

   @elseif ($j['type'] == "field")
      @php  $current_job = \App\Job::findOrFail($j['id']); @endphp
      <p class="info"> <img class="icon" src="{{  asset('assets/images/icons/' .  implode( ",", $current_job->getRelatedCategoriesImage()))}}" />{{ implode( ", ", $current_job->getRelatedCategoriesTitle())  }}</p>
   @endif
```

As you can see, I want to have access to my Model inside my view so I can call a function. It's working like this, but I know it's not a good practice to define a variable inside my view.
So what can I do to get my $current_job or $current_project Model without define it like that:

```
@php   $current_project = \App\Project::findOrFail($j['id']); @endphp
```

Comment: Why don't you send the the three variable as collections of models to the view without converting them to array ??

Comment: I find easier to convert them to array so I can merge them easily.

Comment: why you need to merge them in the first place ? you can loop over each type !! and one more time think you have access to `goalPercentage` property like this `$j['goalPercentage']` !!

Comment: @Maraboc `{!! 'Why do you repeat interpunction signs?' !!}`

Comment: @Tpojka it's just a bad habit that i have :p i will try to fix it ;)

Comment: @Maraboc :D :thumbup:

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the variable `$current_project` from the controller into your view like this:

```
$current_project = \App\Project::findOrFail($j['id']);

return view('view_name', ['current_project' => $current_project]);
```

and then access it in your view.

Answer (score -1):

yes you can call model in your view like this way

```
    @php
    use App\Category;
    use App\Exchange;
    @endphp
```

here category and Exchange is my model, you can use like this way , make object of that model
     $exchange = new Exchange();
now you can access $exchange variable in your blade any where